# React promise resolution not resulting in render

Tags: reactjs, api, promise

So I have a component that performs an API call that gets returned via Promise:

```
getStuff(url).then(val => this.setState(prevState => {prevState.alltime = val}));
```

this is getting called in componentDidMount and is successfully resolving to an array in state.

I also have a component that I am mapping this array into,

```
 const relevantData = this.state[this.state.sortType];
let items= <p> no data</p>;
if (relevantData){
  items = relevantData.map((prop, i) => {
  prop.i = i;
  return(<BoardItem prop={prop} i={i} key={i}/>)})
}
```

and then in the render function

```
<div> {items} </div>
```

nothing renders when I see the promise resolve in the console,  but the next time I render irrelevant state, (such as running $r.setState({test:'test}) in react devtools)  everything renders out.

Comment: Try not mutating previous state, return the new state. `this.setState({ alltime: val })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting state should return a single object representing the (modified) state properties.

Inside your `componentDidMount` method, the correct syntax would be:

```
getStuff(url).then(val => this.setState({ alltime: val }));
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly for more info.

Comment: thanks!   this solved it.  I've been reading too much about passing functions to setstate.   changing it to a simple object got everything working as expected

Comment: glad it worked @BenHart. Please mark it as solution if it's okay for you. Tnx